# Refrescar datatable cuando se filtra

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo una datatable cargada donde el json me trae un script autoejecutable por registro

Todo funciona bien y se cargan todos los scripts de todos los registros. Mi problema biene cuando hace un filtro que no pasa los scripts de los registros filtrados.

NOTA: el json que me llega no lo puedo modificar y tampoco me interesa poner `serversider:true` y filtrar, ya que me traigo todos los registros de golpe

la datatable es muy sencilla

```
$('#tablaResult').dataTable({
    "ajax": "ajax/listadoCliFibraEmpresa.php",
    "serverSide": false
})
```

Y el json que viene es algo así

```
[
  [ "111", "<button>hola</button> <script>console.log('111')</script>" ], 
  [ "222", "<button>hola</button> <script>console.log('222')</script>"]]
]
```

cuando filtre con 111 en el log solo ejecute el script del registro 111

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agregar el código que realiza la acción de filtrado. Dicho sea de paso un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) sería lo optimo.

Comment: @Marcos Si no he puesto un ejemplo es porque no tengo codigo que explique más de lo que he dicho. no tengo funcion de filtrado, utilizo el nativo de las datatables.

Comment: El json que recibes es inválido (hay dos corchetes de cierre al final del segundo elemento). No sé si es un fallo al copiar el ejemplo a la pregunta o si realmente es la causa del problema.